# Why doesn't VBA for Excel use available CPU capacity?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 17MB Excel worksheet with lots of VBA code.   Some of the operations of the VBA do a lot of computation.  In particular, I have a recompute option that completely recomputes the whole sheet and does quality checks to validate the data integrity.  My computer has Windows 10 Pro, a Core i7 4790 processor (3.6 Ghz), and 12 GB of 1600 Mhz memory.  No other programs are running, and the memory is not even close to fully utilized.

The recompute function runs for about 20 minutes.  When I look at Task Manager, the CPU is never more than about 15% utilized.  This has always been the case with this spreadsheet (I've developing it for several years).  Can anyone tell my why Windows won't/can't allocate more CPU to this task?

Comment: This question might be better suited for SuperUser. There's a question here that might provide some info: https://superuser.com/questions/1025428/limit-excel-cpu-usage#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,you%20want%20Excel%20to%20run.

Comment: What does Resource Monitor show to be the DISK usage and I/O rates?

Comment: VBA is single-threaded so will only run on one CPU